# corrossel com imagens diferentes no mobile e desk

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carousel

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou desenvolvendo um site responsivo, nele vou utilizar um carrossel padrão do bootstrap, porém, vão ser imagens diferentes quando o carrossel estiver no mobile e desk.

Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso, sem utilizar dois elementos?

Vlw pessoal!

Comment: Está a usar media queries? Para separar mobile de desktop? Dê uma olhadela aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Bem vindo

Comment: Porque não usar dois elementos ? Acho que seria até melhor rs. Você pode usar JS para detectar se é mobile ou desktop e lançar as imagens para o elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não daria para usar

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Qualquer dispositivo móvel (telefones ou tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
   ....images mobiles
}else{
   ....images desk
}
```

o arquivo Mobile_Detect.php no site http://mobiledetect.net/